# Vaadin 8 Extension: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Moving an extension from one parent to another is not supported

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin8, vaadin-grid

To init my grids I have a Descriptor-Structure, which builds the grid an put all the stuff a column should have together. Now I pass the descriptor from one two another class. This class uses the descriptor to init a subwindow when a button is clicked. Now the problem is, when I click the button the first time everthing is fine, when I close the subwindow and click on the button again I get the following exception:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Moving an extension from one parent to another is not supported

I have no clue what I'm doing wrong and what I should do to fix this problem.

Comment: Without some relevant code it's not clear what you are doing...

Comment: Stacktrace of that exception might also help

Comment: Well I figured the Problem out, the problem was that the Descriptor was passed to the other class. The other class uses the Descriptor to initialize a dialog on a button click. Well it seems that Vaadin doesn't like, that a object is used in more than one object.